# How to get the proper UINotification when selected on locked screen

Tags: ios, swift

Here is my scenario:

The app receives some notifications, in order to be able to have actions on  my locked screen they are in silent mode (content-available = 1 on aps payload).

In **didReceiveRemoteNotification** callback I save it to core data (background or foreground).

My problem is:

Assuming the app was already running and I have locked the screen, when I tap on some notification no callback is called. So far I'm not able to find the proper callback that handles this event.

Am I missing something?

I need to have the notification list saved and be able to go to the proper view when some notification arrives (and is tapped).
By the way receiving the notification, saving, going to the proper view ... everything works except when the screen is locked.

Comment: You don't 'tap' on the notification, you need to slide it to the right

Comment: Can it help answering the question in anyway?

Comment: I just want to make sure you are activating the notification in the right way. If you are then you should get the notification in `didFinishLaunching`

Comment: @Paulw11 "Assuming the app was already running and I have locked the screen" didFinishLaunching is not called in this case. The app is already running.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect if your app was running when notification came because if application is in inactive state and notification is tapped then `didReceiveRemoteNotification` is called by iOS.

However, if for some reason, application is not running then `didReceiveRemoteNotification` function is not called. In such cases, if user click notification, app is launched by notification and `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` gets called:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    var userinfo : NSDictionary = launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
    print(launchOptions);
    return true
}
```

Please check once in your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function.

Comment: didReceiveRemoteNotification is not called because the payload don't have "content-available" enable. If it does this method is called even on background. http://samwize.com/2015/08/07/how-to-handle-remote-notification-with-background-mode-enabled/